# How to prove that c(n) = -(c(n-1))? (Fibonacci)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

$a(n) = a(n−1)+a(n−2)$  with  $a(0) = 1, a(1) = 1$

$c(n) = a(n)a(n−3) − a(n−1)a(n−2)$

How can I prove that c(n) equals -c(n-1)?

And that c(n) = (-1)^(n+1)?

Answer (score -1):

> How can I prove that c(n) equals -c(n-1)?

$$c(n) = a(n)a(n-3) - a(n-1)a(n-2) = $$
$$ =(a(n-1)+a(n-2))a(n-3) - a(n-1)(a(n-3)+a(n-4)) = $$
$$ = a(n-1)a(n-3) + a(n-2)a(n-3) - a(n-1)a(n-3) - a(n-1)a(n-4) = $$
$$ = a(n-2)a(n-3) - a(n-1)a(n-4) = -c(n-1)$$

> And that c(n) = (-1)^(n+1)?

This follows from the above by induction. First we calculate $a(2) = a(1) + a(0) = 2$ and $a(3) = a(2) + a(1) = 3$. Now we have for $n=3$ the base case
$$c(3) = a(3)a(0) - a(2)a(1) = 3 - 2 = 1 = (-1)^4.$$
For the induction step we assume $c(p) = (-1)^{p+1}$ for some $p \geq 3$. Now by the above $$c(p+1) = -c(p) = -1\cdot(-1)^{p+1} = (-1)^{p+2} = (-1)^{(p+1) + 1}.$$
The statement holds for $n = p+1$, and we are done.